# How should I wrap a MemoryStream to have access to the data that was written to it even after it is closed

Tags: c#, stream

I am attempting to use a ThirdParty library to write some data to a MemoryStream so that I can compare the output as part of some unit tests. Unfortunately the Third Party library closes the MemoryStream during execution of it `Save()` method.

Thus I have the following code:

```
byte[] expected = LoadExpectedResult("Test1");
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream()) {
    ThirdPartyLibrary.Save(memoryStream);
    var result = memoryStream.ToArray();
    ConfirmBinaryBlobsAreSufficentlyEqual(expected, result);
}
```

Unfortunately it appears that the `memoryStream.ToArray()` function is only returning the last 3398 bytes that were the last loaded into the buffer as it has been disposed as part of the save process.

Is there anything I can wrap the MemoryStream in so that as data is written to it, it gets read out or written to another memory stream so that when it is disposed of I can still have access to the data.

**Update**

For clarity the `Save()` method also does the writing out so before it is called the MemoryStream is empty. I think the writers of the library expected you to only pass in FileStreams.

Comment: Can't you do a ToArray() *before* calling the third party library?

Comment: That seems to be a bug in the third party library. You can save something to a stream, but closing or disposing it should really not be the Save functions business.

Comment: Unfortunately before the `.Save()` method there is no data in the memory stream to write out. Inside the `.Save()` method it does both the writing and the dsiposing.

Comment: @JamesRobinson Does the method accepts a MemoryStream or any Stream type?

Comment: It will take any Stream

Comment: What about a FileStream instead ? At least your data would be persisted.

Comment: Yeah FileStream is what gets used in the actual production code but for testing I didn't really want to be writing to a temporary file, just seemed sloppy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with:

```
public class MyMemoryStream : MemoryStream
{
    public bool CanDispose { get; set; }

    public override void Close()
    {
        if (!CanDispose)
        {
            return;
        }

        base.Close();
    }
}
```

In the Stream class, the `Dispose()` calls `Close()` that then calls `Dispose(bool disposing)`. `Close()` is `virtual`, so I overrode it.

After using the stream, set `CanDispose = true` and then let it be disposed normally.

```
byte[] expected = LoadExpectedResult("Test1");
using (var memoryStream = new MyMemoryStream()) {
    // implicitly memoryStream.CanDispose == false;
    ThirdPartyLibrary.Save(memoryStream);
    var result = memoryStream.ToArray();
    ConfirmBinaryBlobsAreSufficentlyEqual(expected, result);
    memoryStream.CanDispose = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To circumvent the bug/behaviour: you could either copy the memorystream to a second instance or write it to some temp-file before calling ThirdPartyLibrary.Save.

Comment: Hi Josef I don't this would work as the MemoryStream is empty prior to execution of the Save method

Comment: ah i see. So maybe you could test / assert the result, where ever ThirdPartyLibrary.Save saves the memory stream to?